# iOS Table View, change the frame of table indexes

Tags: ios, uitableview, indexing

I am using a TableView with a search bar and a scope bar.
I have added section indexes on the right of the window.

```
myTableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
searchBar.delegate = self;
searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
searchBar.showsScopeBar = YES;
```

The first section indexes are drawn above the search bar and the scope bar.

How can the frame of the indexes column be changed ?

Thanks

Lionel

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What do you mean by "the first section indexes are drawn above the search bar and the scope bar"??Could you post your screenshot

Comment: Sure. Screenshot added to the question. The indexes C & D are drawn above the search and scope bar.

Comment: Below answer may work I m not sure about that.But you need to post your codes about setting indexes.

Answer (score 0):

So then, one or two rows of your `tableView` is `hiding behind your scope bar and search bar`. The problem is you need to `bind a tableView to your scopeBar`. So then it will bind tableView below your scope bar.

Try like this in your code:

```
//tableView is a table outlet name
//scopeBar is your scope bar outlet name

[tableView setTableHeaderView:scopeBar];
```

This code will bind your `tableView` with `scope bar`.Then the table view rows will `not behind the scope bar` instead of that it will `show down to that bar`.

Comment: In my code, the UISearchBar is bound to the tableView, I added a code snippet to my question.